# Printing Unspecified Number of Array Contents in Google Sheets Cells (GAS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am collecting information from a database, based on a filter and is stored in an array of arrays. Once this information is collected I want to be able to print this data onto a new sheet like this:

```
___________________________________  
|*****|John Buck, Associate, Luxura|
------------------------------------
|*****|Jane Doe, Manager, Eclipse  |
------------------------------------
|*****|Jim Bob, Executive, Lokia   |
------------------------------------
|*****|Suzzy Sue, Director, RoomX  |
___________________________________
```

The most important part is that each time I run this function the array may be a different size, so I need it to continue through the array until all records have been printed down the sheet. I've tried a few things, but I am only used to using forEach or for loops when there is a condition, where as this one would just print the specified info in every array.

```
function testArray() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var activeCell = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveCell();

  var startCell = activeSheet.getRange(5, 4);
  var ratingStartCell = activeSheet.getRange(5, 3);

  var newArray = [
    ["John Buck", "*****", "Associate", "Luxura"][
      ("Jane Doe", "****", "Manager", "Eclipse")
    ][("Jim Bob", "***", "Executive", "lokia")][
      ("Suzzy Sue", "*****", "Director", "RoomX")
    ],
  ];

  newArray.forEach((r, o) => {
    startCell.setValues(
      newArray[r][0] +
        ", " +
        newArray[r][2] +
        ", " +
        newArray[r][3] +
        ", " +
        newArray[r][4]
    );
  });

  newArray.forEach((r, o) => {
    ratingStartCell.setValues(newArray[r][2]);
  });
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `var newArray = [["John Buck", "*****", "Associate", "Luxura"][("Jane Doe", "****", "Manager", "Eclipse")][("Jim Bob", "***", "Executive", "lokia")][("Suzzy Sue", "*****", "Director", "RoomX")],];`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: My goal is to print all the info from the array into google sheets cells, with all information from each candidate in the same cell minus the "****" column. Then the next candidate's information would go into the next cell down and so on until it's finished the whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I modified your array. I'm not sure why it contains "()", you can refer to [JavaScript Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) to learn more on how to declare and use arrays.

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
function testArray() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(activeSheet.getSheetName());

  var newArray = [
    ["John Buck", "*****", "Associate", "Luxura"],
    ["Jane Doe", "****", "Manager", "Eclipse"],
    ["Jim Bob", "***", "Executive", "lokia"],
    ["Suzzy Sue", "*****", "Director", "RoomX"]
  ];
  Logger.log(newArray);

  //Create new array that will contain expected row values
  var rowValues = [];
  newArray.forEach((r,o)=>{
    //Push a 2-D array, Col1 will be the rating (****) while Col2 will be the remaining strings
    //separated by a comma and space
    rowValues.push([r[1], r[0]+", "+r[2]+", "+r[3]]);    
  });
  Logger.log(rowValues);
  //Set the values for the selected range, using the size of the 2-d array starting from row 5.
  activeSheet.getRange(5,3,rowValues.length,rowValues[0].length).setValues(rowValues);
 
}
```

### What it does?

1. After fixing your array, I created a new array `rowValues` which will contain 2 information:

   - Rating
   - Concatenated strings separated by a comma and a space.
2. Once I have created the desired grouping and output for each row. I now set the values of the selected range based on the `rowValues` created using [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [Range.setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

> I set the start row to 5 and start column to 3 based on your earlier example. Feel free to adjust your start row and column index based on your preference.

### OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could post the newArray to activeSheet in one go using the `setValues(values)` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

This is more efficient than writing to the sheet on cell at a time. See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

```
activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, newArray.length, newArray[0].length).setValues(newArray);
```

The size of the array does not need to be specified. `newArray.length` is the number of rows and `newArray[0].length` is the number of columns.

You need to be careful when constructing the array: each row must have the same number of columns. If the number of columns is different, you'll get an error and the `setValues()` will fail.

Comment: This would bring all of my information into the new sheet, but wouldn't format the information I'm looking for. This would put each piece of information one by one in their own cell. I want to be able to put all info except rating to be in the same cell separated by a comma and space.